# Морфологический способ выражения слов

Tags: морфология

### Помогите, пожалуйста, проверить правильность выполненного задания.

Меня (мест.) беспокоит (глагол), что (союз) говорит (глагол) Звяк-Нога (сущ.). Все (мест.) наши (мест.) слушают (глагол), что (союз) он (мест.) говорит (глагол). Но (союз) люди(сущ.) не (частица) знают (глагол). Он (мест.) никогда (нареч.) не (частица) говорит (глагол.) то (мест.), что (союз) он (мест.) говорит (глагол), когда (союз) люди (сущ.) могут (глагол) услышать (глагол). Люди (сущ.) могут (глагол) обидеться (глагол).

Звяк-Нога (сущ.) путешествует (глагол). Туда-сюда (наречие). Иногда (наречие) далеко (наречие). Часто (наречие) возвращается (глагол) рассказать (глагол) нам (мест.). Хотя (союз) почему (наречие) он (мест.) рассказывает (глагол) нам (мест.) снова (наречие) и (союз) снова (наречие), я (мест.) не (частица) понимаю (глагол).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ДомЗад

Comment: Человек же выполнил, просит проверить.Зачем закрывать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все (мест.) наши (**сущ. , или субстантивированное мест.**) слушают , что (**союзное слово, выраженное местоимением**) он говорит . Он никогда  не  говорит  то , что (**союзное слово, выраженное местоимением)** он  говорит , когда люди  могут услышать .

Остальное верно.